# Can someone explain databases, server hosting, database communication (like accessing them from software/games securely), etc?

Tags: database, server, hosting, game-development

I am pretty much a noob with web stuff. I make video games and some software. One thing I've always wanted to make is a video game with accounts and multiplayer features. I can make multiplayer games, but only ones where a player hosts a private server on their own machine and their friends connect directly with their IP address and port.

I want to learn everything I need to know to get started with hosting databases, how to access and modify them, and how to do it securely from within a public game or other software, or how to do it from a website using PHP or something else. I also don't know how to host video game servers, or how server instances work for individual matches. I've looked at Amazon AWS for this, though, but I've never tried it.

Are there resources you could point out to me to get started? I tried learning SQL on code academy but it doesn't teach how to host databases or actually use them in a live production. I want to at least get some test demos working to learn first-hand how to do it all.

Sorry if this question doesn't belong here; I'm not sure where else I should post such a question.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 manage.py runserver
Than enter
Than ip address like 127.0.0.1
Settings.py
Allowed host=('127.0.0.1')
Than runserver